# react-router-redux, push method does not work

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I am using react-router-redux.

I don't know how to create the demo to describe the issue simply.
I push all code on Github.
https://github.com/jiexishede/newReactSOAskDemo001

The `a-href` work well. 
@https://github.com/jiexishede/newReactSOAskDemo001/blob/ask1/src/components/Home/Preview.js/#L37

Now, the push method does not work.
@https://github.com/jiexishede/newReactSOAskDemo001/blob/ask1/src/components/Home/Preview.js/#L30

I edit the code and update it on GitHub.

I import the `hashHistory`.

https://github.com/jiexishede/newReactSOAskDemo001/blob/286fc0e07f9d9c863f7c4fc8d9b2c09a2c45e231/src/components/Home/Preview.js#L9

`hashHistory.push('detail/'+id);` work well.
https://github.com/jiexishede/newReactSOAskDemo001/blob/286fc0e07f9d9c863f7c4fc8d9b2c09a2c45e231/src/components/Home/Preview.js#L32

`disPatchpush` @https://github.com/jiexishede/newReactSOAskDemo001/blob/286fc0e07f9d9c863f7c4fc8d9b2c09a2c45e231/src/components/Home/Preview.js#L31
It does not work.

In the `Home.js`:

```
  @connect(state => {
  return {
    list:state.home.list,

  };
}, dispatch => {

  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
    dispatchPush:  bindActionCreators(push, dispatch),
  }
})
```

`dispatchPush` is passed from the `Home.js` to `PreviewList` to `Preview`.

Answer (score 3):

Have your tried out?

```
handleClick(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.props.history.push('/#/detail/' + id);
```

}

Tell me if it works or not and will update the answer accordingly.

Or if you want to try to navigate outside of components, try [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/95094769caca201b8e9afe68ff3d6cb4ff280fac/docs/advanced/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md).

Also try setting a route:

```
 <Route path="/preview" component={Preview} />
```

That might get you the history prop.

Comment: `this.props` doesn't have the `history`.

Comment: What about the other link I gave?

Comment: `react-router-redux` has a push method. I want to use that push method. I want to know how to use the `react-router-redux`.

Comment: @jiexishede Something like this?  https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions

Answer (score 2):

you miss routerMiddleware. Works beautifully after applying routerMiddleware.

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
...
const finalCreateStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(
      ThunkMiddleware, 
      FetchMiddleware, 
      routerMiddleware(browserHistory)
  ),
  DevTools.instrument(),
)(createStore);


const reducer = combineReducers({
  ...rootReducer,
  routing: routerReducer,
});

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = finalCreateStore(reducer, initialState);
  return store;
}
```

Read this section of the docs - https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to another route, try Proptypes, like so:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class Preview extends Component {
        ...
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };
  handleNavigate(id,e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.push(`/#/detail/${id}`);
  }
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `react-router-redux` and solved in the following way.

There is need to use `Router` not `BrowserRouter`. The `history` object has to be created with the `createBrowserHistory` method imported from `history` package.

Then the history has to be synchronized with the store using `syncHistoryWithStore` method imported from `react-router-redux`. This new history object will be passed to `Router`.

Then initialize the `routerMiddleware` passing to it the synchronized history object.

**Please check out this code:**

**store.js**

```
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware as reduxRouterMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { category, machine, machines, core } from './reducers';
import rootSaga from './sagas';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    category,
    machines,
    machine,
    core,
    routing: routerReducer,
});


const initStore = (history = {}) => {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const routerMiddleware = reduxRouterMiddleware(history);

    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer, 
        applyMiddleware(
            sagaMiddleware, 
            routerMiddleware
        )
    );

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

    return store;
}

export default initStore;
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import initStore from './store';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

const store = initStore(browserHistory)
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

Connected React Router requires React 16.4 and React Redux 6.0 or later.

```
$ npm install --save connected-react-router
```

Or

```
$ yarn add connected-react-router
```

Usage
Step 1

In your root reducer file,

Create a function that takes history as an argument and returns a root reducer.
Add router reducer into root reducer by passing history to connectRouter.
Note: The key MUST be router.

```
// reducers.js

import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

const createRootReducer = (history) => combineReducers({
  router: connectRouter(history),
  ... // rest of your reducers
})
export default createRootReducer
```

Step 2

When creating a Redux store,

Create a history object.
Provide the created history to the root reducer creator.
Use routerMiddleware(history) if you want to dispatch history actions (e.g. to change URL with push('/path/to/somewhere')).

```
// configureStore.js

import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import createRootReducer from './reducers'
...
export const history = createBrowserHistory()

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  const store = createStore(
    createRootReducer(history), // root reducer with router state
    preloadedState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        routerMiddleware(history), // for dispatching history actions
        // ... other middlewares ...
      ),
    ),
  )

  return store
}
```

Step 3

Wrap your react-router v4/v5 routing with ConnectedRouter and pass the history object as a prop. Remember to delete any usage of BrowserRouter or NativeRouter as leaving this in will cause problems synchronising the state.
Place ConnectedRouter as a child of react-redux's Provider.
N.B. If doing server-side rendering, you should still use the StaticRouter from react-router on the server.

```
// index.js

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router' // react-router v4/v5
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import configureStore, { history } from './configureStore'
...
const store = configureStore(/* provide initial state if any */)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}> { /* place ConnectedRouter under Provider */ }
      <> { /* your usual react-router v4/v5 routing */ }
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<div>Match</div>)} />
          <Route render={() => (<div>Miss</div>)} />
        </Switch>
      </>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('react-root')
)
```